# How to invoke a ReST endpoint (deployed in AWS API Gateway using IAM permissions) using AWS Java SDK v2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Anybody can point me to the documentation / proper AWS Java SDK v2 where it's described how to use 'default AWS credentials provider chain' (which would pick up the role configured for my EC2 instance)?
They say in the general documentation that I don't need to 'manually' sign the HTTP request.

But I struggle to find documentation/examples of SDK helper(?) classes which would do the signing of the HTTP (specifically in SDK v2).

A bit more clarification.
When I generate API client code (from the deployed API) it still uses SDK v1 classes internally.
The question is basically: how to port functionality like

```
        HttpResponseHandler<DeleteFtpuserResult> responseHandler = protocolFactory.createResponseHandler(new JsonOperationMetadata().withPayloadJson(true)
            .withHasStreamingSuccessResponse(false), new DeleteFtpuserResultJsonUnmarshaller());

    HttpResponseHandler<SdkBaseException> errorResponseHandler = createErrorResponseHandler(new JsonErrorShapeMetadata().withModeledClass(
            BadRequestException.class).withHttpStatusCode(400));

    return clientHandler.execute(new ClientExecutionParams<DeleteFtpuserRequest, DeleteFtpuserResult>()
            .withMarshaller(new DeleteFtpuserRequestProtocolMarshaller(protocolFactory)).withResponseHandler(responseHandler)
            .withErrorResponseHandler(errorResponseHandler).withInput(deleteFtpuserRequest));
```

to SDK v2?

Comment: It's unclear what problem you're having.  There are plenty of examples of how to interact with AWS services using the Java SDK2 - [here is S3 for example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3.html).  There isn't a need to sign anything as the library takes care of that for you.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: the problem is i don't need to interact with a service.
i need 2 make an HTTP request 2 an API GW url (like https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/LATEST) but without manually generating signature.

the SDK v1 has support for that signing (like it's implemented here: https://inspeerity.com/blog/how-to-call-aws-api-gateway-from-the-java-code).
i can't find support for this in SDK v2.

even 'autogenerated' client code still depends on SDK v1 and uses the same principle of creating a signed http request)

Comment: The [default credential provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html) is the search order normally used by the SDK to find credentials and authenticate for you (e.g. an env var). But what specific issues/errors are you encountering with using the generated code, as that is one of the recommended methods of invocation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-apigateway-generated-java-sdk.html

Comment: @qix i know. but...
1. the 'generated client' might not be available
2. the 'generated client' is useless because the API is not defined correctly in terms of data mappings of the response (my case. and i can't do nothing about it, the API is beyond my control)
3. the 'generated client' still depends on SDK v1. Should I want to use SDK v2 only it renders that 'generated client' code useless

Thus I was looking for more 'general' solution but could not find any SDK v2 helper classes which would allow me not to code HTTP request signatures.